# Outlook Add-in,group emails based on color category

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I need to set the sub folder group by property through my c# outlook add-in code

basically, i got mails in the folder with different color categories.i need to sort them through my code

Initially i thought of sorting:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems =m_Outlook.Inbox.Items;
oItems.Sort("[Categories]");

dosnt work... :(
Pretty much lost here

Also trying bubble sorting :

but cant assign mail item to next index

object objMessage = subFolder.Items[counter];
object objNextMessage = subFolder.Items[counter + 1];

subFolder.Items[counter] = objNextMessage;
subFolder.Items[counter + 1] = objNextMessage;

Error:   Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Items.this[object]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

---

Sorting seemed a difficult option so i thought of grouping .
how do i go about it ?

Cheers!
Rajat

Answer (score 0):

Sort will re-order the items in the collection but won't update the view:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.sort.aspx

You'd need to set the collection to be displayed again after sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but items.sort is not applicable here as the sorting is to be done on a multi-valued property(category) . I was hoping for some ' Group By' solution ....

Comment: Can you copy the items into a custom collection (something implements IEnumberable) sort them and then assign them back to the view?

Comment: hmmmm..so move items to a temp folder when color coding . then moving items based on category to actual folder.deleting the temp folder  ?

Comment: Ok, i got your suggestion...adding the items to a list and then sorting...hmm good thought,i tried it also . but the prob remains . the custom list gets sorted , no issues there . whne i try moving the mails back to the folder the mails again come in date order (which is obvious )....as ai said previously a grouping would be a feasible option